# Xcode iPad simulator keyboard opens in middle of screen

Tags: xcode, ipad, keyboard

I am running xcode 4.3.2 and just started having the following problem.

All projects running in the simulator are positioning the popup keyboard in the center of the IPAD simulator. The IPHONE simulator is fine with the normal keyboard positioned at the bottom of the screen. Even a simple new project with a single text field shows the keyboard in the middle of the screen with equal amounts of white space above and bellow. This occurs in all orientations.

Interestingly, UIPickerViews also exhibit the same behavior.

This is driving me nuts, as it has been fine for many months and now all the objects (text fields etc.) are hidden when the keyboard plops down smack in the middle of the screen.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature of the iPad. You can "drag" the keyboard with the drag handle in the lower-right hand corner of the keyboard. The image [from this blog post](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/16957/ios-5-how-to-enable-the-ipads-split-keyboard/) by Rob Rogers indicates how to use it. My guess is you inadvertently moved your keyboard.

[image]

Comment: Wow, you guys are amazing!! Worked like a charm. Thanks for the super fast response.